# check if two objects have the same attribute in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
class User:
    """A user class"""

    def __init__(self, username, father)
        """Initialize the user class"""
        self.username = name
        self.father = father

def main():
    user1 = User("foo", "oldman")
    user2 = User("bar", "oldman1")
```

Assume I have more people to fill in their data, and they will have all kind of different inputs about their father's name. How can I make a function to check if two or more objects have the same father attribute in python?

Comment: As in ``user1.father == user2.father``?

Comment: sometimes yes..

Comment: Which times not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class User:
    """A user class"""

    def __init__(self, name, father):
        """Initialize the user class"""
        self.username = name
        self.father = father
    def check_father(self,user):
      if(self.father==user.father):
        return True
      return False

def main():
    user1 = User("foo", "oldman")
    user2 = User("bar", "oldman1")
    print(user2.check_father(user1))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```